# Making a method select the location of a file using recursion

Tags: python

I'm trying to create a recursive method; the goal of this method is to find the deepest directory that could contain this file and determine if the file belongs here. If the file does I want it to return the full file location. the first method was the original, but it didn't work with a return statement.

```
import zipfile, lxml.etree, os, xml.etree.ElementTree as ET, sys, shutil, re
from docx import Document

path = #Directory where you want files sorted to
```

## Orignial method

```
def findSubDir(file,dire):
tempPath = os.path.join(path,dire.replace(" ",""))
for dirs in os.listdir(tempPath):
    if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(tempPath,dirs)):
        for names in re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]+', dirs):
            if names in file:
                print(os.path.join(tempPath,dirs))
                findSubDir(file,os.path.join(dire,dirs))
```

## Modified method

```
def reFindSubDir(file,dire):
    tempPath = os.path.join(path,dire.replace(" ",""))
    dirs = [dirs for dirs in os.listdir(tempPath)
if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(tempPath,dirs))]
    if(any(os.path.isdir(os.path.join(tempPath,dirs)) for dirs in os.listdir(tempPath))):
        print("passed")
        folder = "".join([names for dires in dirs for names in re.findall('[A-Z][^A-Z]+', dires)if names in file])
        print("folder")
        if folder != "":
            reFindSubDir(file,os.path.join(dire,folder))
        else:
            print("Steve2")
            return "Steve"
    else:
        print(tempPath)
        return(tempPath)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues I immediately see in your code. First, in your original attempt it appears you are missing a base case. Second, you're not returning anything in your recursive case.

Try using this first without your regex, then you can incorporate it into your code.

```
def findSubDir(file, dire=""):
    tempPath = os.path.join(path, dire)

    for dirs in os.listdir(tempPath):

        if os.path.isdir(os.path.join(tempPath, dirs)):
            return findSubDir(file,os.path.join(tempPath,dirs))

        if dirs == file:
            return os.path.join(tempPath, file)
```

Comment: To your second point, that is my issue I am unsure why the return method is not working. I am trying out your adjustment for the first method.

Comment: You need to actually return the recursive call. Your function evaluates it but doesn't return anything. Notice how I added 'return' before calling the function recursively.